# Запрос текущего местоположения без запуска Provider'ов

Tags: java, android, геолокация

Мне нужно получать локацию пользователя раз  в полчаса. 
Есть следующик код:

```
 public static Location getLastKnownLoaction(boolean enabledProvidersOnly, Context context) {
        LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Location utilLocation = null;
        List<String> providers = manager.getProviders(enabledProvidersOnly);
        for (String provider : providers) {
            utilLocation = manager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
            if(utilLocation != null) return utilLocation;
        }
        return null;
}
```

Но насколько я понимаю если провайдер не был запущен, то я могу не получить этих  данных о местоположении.

Или же такой код, но он может сьедать заряд батареи.

```
public class LocationService implements LocationListener {

    static Location imHere; 
    public static void SetUpLocationListener(Context context) // это нужно запустить в самом начале работы программы
    {
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        LocationListener locationListener = new LocationService();

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                5000,
                10,
                locationListener); 

        imHere = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        imHere = loc;
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }
}
```

**Вопрос**: как можно получать локацию пользователя не запуская провайдеры и с минимальным потреблением батарейки?

Comment: вам нужен Play Services 
FusedLocationProviderClient

Comment: но при этом местоположение должно быть точным?

Comment: @iFr0z вообще хотелось бы точно, но там не принципиально,  небольшая погрешность допускается!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я изпользовал [FusedLocationProviderClient](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html)

Он лучше работает, проверяет по GPS если его нет, по wifi и т.д. в доке все есть.

Comment: Чем он отличается от второго варианта кода? В чем его приимущество?

Comment: Тем что когда я отвечал, второго варианта еще не было ). Ну и LocationManager отходит на задний план. В доке все есть.

Comment: Вас понял, уже добавил к себе в проект, спасибо!